# Load multiple files using HTML5 and PHP

Tags: php, file, html, input

I am trying to load multiple files using HTML5.
This is my code I found on some site.
In the PHP code it doesn't recognize it as an array.

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone show me a working solution?

Thanks.

index.html

```
<form action='save.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input name="uploads" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
<input type='submit' value="Upload File">
</form>
```

save.php

```
function GetFiles() {
        $files = array();
        $fdata = $_FILES["uploads"];
        if (is_array($fdata["name"])) {//This is the problem
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i) {
                        $files[] = array(
                            'name' => $fdata['name'][$i],
                            'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i],
                        );
                }
        } else {
                $files[] = $fdata;
        }

        foreach ($files as $file) {
                // uploaded location of file is $file['tmp_name']
                // original filename of file is $file['file']
        }
}
```

Comment: The answers below have correctly solved the problem, and here's a page with a complete working example that might help someone else who stumbles upon this page:  http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/29/quick-php-tip-uploading-multiple-files-in-html5/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make some sort of array of the name:

```
<input name="uploads[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

Just like you used to do when using checkboxes.

Answer (score 7):

form variables that are arrays must be named with a `[]`, otherwise PHP doesn't see it as an array.  So:

```
<form action='save.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
<input name="uploads[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" /> 
<input type='submit' value="Upload File"> 
</form>
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of a old thread but I use this little script to convert the (to me) confusing layout of the $_FILES array to a more readable form. Name_input is whatever name you gave to the Input object in HTML.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['name_input']['name']); $i++) {
    $betterfiles[] = array(
        "name" => $_FILES['name_input']['name'][$i],
        "type" => $_FILES['name_input']['type'][$i],
        "tmp_name" => $_FILES['name_input']['tmp_name'][$i],
        "error" => $_FILES['name_input']['error'][$i],
        "size" => $_FILES['name_input']['size'][$i]
    );
}
```